# AJAX function not working in IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, iis-7

I have an asp mvc 3 application, and there is a view that makes an ajax call, when I run it in visualstudio it workes but when i run it in IIS 7 it is not sending it to the server! I searched for a solution and it said that the urls had to be modified, so i changed it like this using url action but it still doesn't do anything, does anybody know why this might be?

In the webpage I don't see anymessage it simply doesn't do anything.

The ajax funciton is inside the code of the view, it is embedded there, it looks like:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 function display(Txt) {
 $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  //url: "/Controller/Action",
                  url: '@Url.Action("Controller", "Action")',
                  data: "Id=" + Txt,
                  success: function (result) {
                      if (result.Info != undefined) {

            //do something

                      }
                      else if (result.Info == undefined) {
                          //do something
                      }
                  }
              });

}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you physically access the url?

Comment: @Darin - no need to be a jerk.

Comment: @Jack Marchetti, I am just sick of seeing questions like this. I know I am a jerk but there is nothing I can do about it. That's how I am.

Comment: I corrected the question, no problem

Comment: With all due respect, Darin might seem like a jerk, but dudes answered my questions in both a jerky and non jerky way, and he knows his stuff.

Comment: I can access the url because i programmed it to handle ajax petitions and non-ajax petition.

Comment: @bb2, what happens when you inspect with FireBug? Do you see the AJAX request? Do you see the response from the server? What is the status code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that Url.Action was the other way around:

```
before:
url: '@Url.Action("Controller", "Action")',

after:

    url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")',
```

This is strange because  I checked a blog from microsoft and they had it in the first order =S

Answer (score 0):

First try getting to the Ajax uri in your browser.
If you cannot you may just have set the app up in a different folder structure.
If your controller method has an Ajax attribute remove it for this test.
The answer may be apparent after trying the url (uri)